# Alternate Mongo DB query for MySQL query

Tags: mysql, mongodb

As a part of migration from MySQL to MongoDB,I am trying to rewrite all  the mySQL queries into MongoDB queries.I am able to successfully do the same,except for a query

MySQL query:

```
SELECT(select job_status from indexjob order by job_timestamp desc limit 1) AS job_status,(select job_timestamp from indexjob where job_status='SUCCESS' order by job_timestamp desc limit 1) AS job_timestamp;
```

MongoDB data structure:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590caba811ef2308585f0dbb"),
    "_class" : "com.info.sample.bean.IndexJobBean",
    "jobName" : "IndexJob",
    "jobStatus" : "SUCCESS",
    "timeStamp" : "2017.05.05.22.13.19"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590caf1711ef23082cc58a3b"),
    "_class" : "com.info.sample.bean.IndexJobBean",
    "jobName" : "IndexJob",
    "jobStatus" : "FAILED",
    "timeStamp" : "2017.05.05.22.27.59"
}
```

**edit - from comments**
The query should return the timestamp of last jobStatus="SUCCESS" and the last jobStatus(it can be SUCCESS or FAILED). In MySQL I fetched these in such a way the result will be a row with columns jobStatus and timestamp with the respective values.

Comment: Without seeing how you organized your data in MongoDB, it's going to be difficult (or impossible) to even imagine how you'd query it. Please edit your question with at least a bit of sample content.

Comment: I have edited the content

Comment: Ok, great. But now, you should also show what your expected results are. Again, relational data doesn't map directly to document collections. What is the query supposed to achieve?

Comment: The query should return the timestamp of last  jobStatus="SUCCESS" and    the last jobStatus(it can be SUCCESS or FAILED). In MySQL I fetched these in such a way the result will be a row with columns  jobStatus and timestamp with the respective values.

Comment: In the future, *edit* your question; don't bury details in comments. I edited it this time and put your query in the question.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question David.Could you help me in getting the query replaced with mongoDB query